# How to execute a procedure which is inside a package?

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, procedures

There is a package ABC and many procedures inside it. I want to execute a single procedure inside that (say xyz). I used the below commands

```
begin
ABC.xyz;
end;
```

I am not able to run the same. Can any one help as I am getting Unexpected symbol "BEGIN" error

Comment: try `execute ABC.xyz`

Answer (score 4):

**Create Package specification :**

```
create or replace package pkg is
procedure xyz;
end;
```

**Create Package body** :

```
create or replace package body pkg is
procedure xyz is
dbms_output.put_line('hi');
end
end;
```

**Executing**

```
exec pkg.xyz
```

**OR**

```
begin
pkg.xyz;
end;
```

Now, verify your code and see what have you done wrong in your code.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to execute a single procedure inside that (say xyz)

You can call a procedure from a package onnly if you have added it to the **package specification**.

From documentation,

> The package spec contains public declarations. The scope of these
>   declarations is local to your database schema and global to the
>   package. So, the declared items are accessible from your application
>   and from anywhere in the package.

Once you add the procedure to the package spec, you could then call your procedure as package.procedure in a **PL/SQL block**:

```
begin
   ABC.xyz;
end;
```

Or, in **SQL*Plus**:

```
EXECUTE ABC.xyz;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the great answers above: In some cases, the package is only accessible via a specific user account. In out setup we have admin and app users that have access to specific schemas and data so that our applications share a single Oracle installation. Just add the user name where your package and tables are stored.

begin
user.pkg.xyz;
end;